# Did the women tell the disciples or did they say nothing to anyone

Tags: matthew, contradiction, mark, resurrection

Mark 16:8

> So they left the tomb and ran away, overwhelmed with shock and amazement. And in their fear they did not say a word to anyone.

Matthew 28:8

> So they hurried away from the tomb in fear and great joy, and ran to tell His disciples

Answer (score 1):

There are four related parallel passages here (KJV translation):

> Matthew 28:5-7
>
> > <sup>5</sup> *And the angel answered and said unto the women, Fear not ye: for I know that ye seek Jesus, which was crucified.*
> >
> > <sup>6</sup> *He is not here: for he is risen, as he said. Come, see the place where the Lord lay.*
> >
> > <sup>7</sup> *And go quickly, and tell his disciples that he is risen from the dead; and, behold, he goeth before you into Galilee; there shall ye see him: lo, I have told you.*
> >
> > <sup>8</sup> *And they departed quickly from the sepulchre with fear and great joy; and did run to bring his disciples word.*

---

> Mark 16:6-7
>
> > <sup>6</sup> *And he saith unto them, Be not affrighted: Ye seek Jesus of Nazareth, which was crucified: he is risen; he is not here: behold the place where they laid him.*
> >
> > <sup>7</sup> *But go your way, tell his disciples and Peter that he goeth before you into Galilee: there shall ye see him, as he said unto you.*
> >
> > <sup>8</sup> *And they went out quickly, and fled from the sepulchre; for they trembled and were amazed: neither said they any thing to any man; for they were afraid.*

---

> Luke 24:4-8
>
> > <sup>4</sup> *And it came to pass, as they were much perplexed thereabout, behold, two men stood by them in shining garments:*
> >
> > <sup>5</sup> *And as they were afraid, and bowed down their faces to the earth, they said unto them, Why seek ye the living among the dead?*
> >
> > <sup>6</sup> *He is not here, but is risen: remember how he spake unto you when he was yet in Galilee,*
> >
> > <sup>7</sup> *Saying, The Son of man must be delivered into the hands of sinful men, and be crucified, and the third day rise again.*
> >
> > <sup>8</sup> *And they remembered his words*

---

> John 20:1-4
>
> > <sup>1</sup> *The first day of the week cometh Mary Magdalene early, when it was yet dark, unto the sepulchre, and seeth the stone taken away from the sepulchre.*
> >
> > <sup>2</sup> *Then she runneth, and cometh to Simon Peter, and to the other disciple, whom Jesus loved, and saith unto them, They have taken away the Lord out of the sepulchre, and we know not where they have laid him.*
> >
> > <sup>3</sup> *Peter therefore went forth, and that other disciple, and came to the sepulchre.*
> >
> > <sup>4</sup> *So they ran both together: and the other disciple did outrun Peter, and came first to the sepulchre.*

---

[The Diatessaron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatessaron), a 2nd century Syriac harmony of the Gospels, arranges the verses as follows:

> **1**
>
> > <sup>Lk 24:4</sup>
> >
> > > *And it came to pass, as they were much perplexed thereabout, behold, two men stood by them in shining garments:*
> >
> > <sup>Lk 24:5a</sup>
> >
> > > *And as they were afraid,*

---

> **2**
>
> > <sup>Lk 24:5b</sup>
> >
> > > *and bowed down their faces to the earth, they said unto them, Why seek ye the living among the dead?*

---

> **3**
>
> > <sup>Lk 24:6a,Mt 28:6a,Mk 16:6b</sup>
> >
> > > *He is not here, but is risen:*
> >
> > <sup>Lk 24:6b-7a</sup>
> >
> > > *remember how he spake unto you when he was yet in Galilee, Saying,*

---

> **4**
>
> > <sup>Lk 24:7b</sup>
> >
> > > *The Son of man must be delivered into the hands of sinful men, and be crucified, and the third day rise again.*

---

> **5**
>
> > <sup>Mt 28:7a, Mk 16:7a</sup>
> >
> > > *And go quickly, and tell his disciples*
> >
> > <sup>Mk 16:7b</sup>
> >
> > > *and Peter*
> >
> > <sup>Mt 28:7b</sup>
> >
> > > *that he is risen from the dead; and, behold,*
> >
> > <sup>Mt 28:7c,Mk 16:7c</sup>
> >
> > > *he goeth before you into Galilee;*

---

> **6**
>
> > <sup>Mt 28:7b, Mk 16:7a</sup>
> >
> > > *there shall ye see him,*
> >
> > <sup>Mk 16:7b</sup>
> >
> > > *as he said unto you.*
> >
> > <sup>Mt 28:7c</sup>
> >
> > > *Lo, I have told you.*

---

> **7**
>
> > <sup>Lk 24:8</sup>
> >
> > > *And they remembered his words,*
> >
> > <sup>Mt 28:8a,Mk 16:8a</sup>
> >
> > > *And they departed quickly from the sepulchre with fear*
> >
> > <sup>Mt 28:8b</sup>
> >
> > > *and great joy; and did run*

---

> **8**
>
> > <sup>Mk 16:8b</sup>
> >
> > > [and] *they trembled and were amazed: neither said they any thing to any man; for they were afraid.*

---

> **9**
>
> > <sup>Jn 20:2</sup>
> >
> > > *Then she* [Mary] *runneth, and cometh to Simon Peter, and to the other disciple, whom Jesus loved, and saith unto them, They have taken away the Lord out of the sepulchre, and we know not where they have laid him.*

---

> **10**
>
> > <sup>Jn 20:3</sup>
> >
> > > *Peter therefore went forth, and that other disciple, and came to the sepulchre.*

---

> **11**
>
> > Jn 20:4
> >
> > > *So they ran both together: and the other disciple did outrun Peter, and came first to the sepulchre.*

---

Thus, according to this understanding, the women set out to tell *the disciples and Peter* (Matthew 28:7, Mark 16:7) and eventually did so (John 20:2ff), but while they were on their way to the disciples they did not speak to anyone (Mark 16:8)

Answer (score -1):

In Matthew 28:8, the phrase "and did run to bring his disciples word" is a summarizing statement which 'word' happened to include Mary Magdalene's encounter with Jesus at the tomb[John 20:14-17]. It is not to be taken as occurring immediately after her encounter with the angel at the tomb[Mark 16:1-8], for other events took place between Mary Magdalene's first encounter with the angel at the tomb and her meeting with Jesus at the tomb, such as her first encounter with two angels at the tomb[Luke 24:1-10], her fetching of Peter to tell of the events at the tomb[John 20:1-2, Luke 24:12], her returning to the tomb with Peter[John 20:3-11], and her second meeting with two angels at the tomb[John 20:11-13]. The statement in Mark 16:8 then refers only to Mary Magdalene's(and others') encounter with the first angel, and deals with their trepidation up until the subsequent two-angel encounter, after which they fetched Peter.